# How to store local copy of email before forwarding (in procmail)

Tags: email, procmail

This forwards emails to the address stored in the variable EMAIL_ADDR

```
:0 
* ^From
! $EMAIL_ADDR
```

I would like to save a local copy of the email before
it's forwarded.  Not sure of the syntax to do that.
I know this doesn't do it:

```
:0 
* ^From
| tee $FILE
! $EMAIL_ADDR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the script below (It is based on [`man procmailex`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/procmailex)).

```
:0 
* ^From
{
   # use lock file to prevent simultaneous deliveries 
   :0 c:tee.lock
   | tee $FILE

   :0
   ! $EMAIL_ADDR
 }
```

Instead of `| tee $FILE` you may use directly name of mailbox-file

Comment: ... Until you wonder why `$FILE` got corrupted one day by unlucky chance, because you didn't use locking.

Comment: @tripleee added lock file

Answer (score 1):

The common approach is to use a "clone" flag.

```
:0c
! $EMAIL_ADDR

# Whatever else you want to do with the message
:0:
$FILE
```

Since every message has a `^From` I assume you were simply not aware that the condition is optional; to unconditionally do something, just omit the condition regex line completely.  If that's not the case, you can group multiple action under a condition with a block of recipes in braces:

```
:0
* common condition
{
   :0c
   ! $EMAIL_ADDR

   :0:
   $FILE
}
```

This is an ancient FAQ; http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#c-flag

You can have multiple conditions, but only one action.  If you like, you could use `tee` to save a copy to a file, then pipe to `$SENDMAIL` instead; but I would recommend against that, because the `tee` output file needs to have a lock file, in order to prevent multiple Procmail processes from delivering interleaved fragments of multiple messages to the same file at the same time; see http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#locking for example.